# How to save orphaned inodes?

Tags: fsck, inode

Is there a way to have fsck save the orphaned inodes so I can inspect what they were instead of having them cleared?

Thanks

Comment: Not really, there's nothing to inspect.

Comment: You should instead be concerned about the *why* you're having orphaned inodes in the first place. Improper shutdown? Drive failing? ...